# SSRS Format and Extract Formula

Tags: reporting-services

I have a field in my SSRS report that has color name.

but sometimes it has 2 colors formatted like so

```
 <font> color=red BLACK </font> / <font> color=black BLUE </font>
```

please note I removed the <> from the line above since it shows as HTML and I cant figure how to make it show as text in this site

what is needed, is an if statement..

that if the field has the format above..  it would display...

OLD color = Black  /   New color = Blue

if it doesn't have the format above it would just display the color name of the field.

any help would be great

[photo of current and what is needed to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBidl.jpg)

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly (and in it's literal sense) ... you should be able to use : =iif(fields!colorname.value = "<font> color=red BLACK </font> / <font> color=black BLUE </font>","OLD color = Black / New color = Blue",fields!colorname.value)

Comment: hi harry.. yes but I don't know what is inbetween the font sections..    <font> color=red> BLACK </font> / <font> color=black> BLUE </font>  it could be yellow..  yellow canary blue..     I need to be able to change old color to be whatever is inbetween the first font section and the new color to be between whatever is the next set of fonts.. or just print out the original value.. if font is not present

Comment: can you show a sample screen shot with hard coded examples on what your desired results are.. your questions isn't very clear..

Comment: hi  see the picture above in the original post

Comment: on the second color format.. does it have the <font> tags? or is it only when you have more than one color? Does your dataset come from SQLServer? Asking so the dataset can be manipulated rather than SSRS

Comment: yes it does.. the reason i need to do it here on SSRS instead sql is this is a shared SP and i cant mess up the original report that this SP was used for this is an offshoot

Comment: closing this.. we got this using the replace command...  i forgot replace already is an inferred IF statement